# Trying to deploy a React/Redux app to Heroku....now I'm getting an R14 memory error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have little experience with Node/Heroku and upon trying to deploy my simple React/Redux app to Heroku, it successfully deploys but only shows an application error. When I look at the logs I get the following error:

```
2020-05-24T18:12:35.402548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=914M(178.6%)
2020-05-24T18:12:35.404076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

as well as

```
2020-05-24T18:18:57.774376+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

When I look up solutions, I run into tuning the garbage collector, or heapdump, all things I've never come across as I'm just deploying my first React app (ever) to Heroku. I've tried changing the package.json to increase the max-memory for **react-scripts build and test**, I've tried

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8172
```

and

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

The last one gave me an error on "import React from 'react' saying "Cannot use import statement outside a module" so it seems like I'm going down a rabbit hole of Node, which is fine if anyone can provide any insight into what may be the source of the craziness. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this deployment include both the server and frontend? If not, is the frontend a create-react-app project?

Comment: This is a create-react-app frontend, and I don't believe there was a server included (to my knowledge anyway.)

Comment: is heroku is must ? or you can use any other ?

Comment: Then Heroku is probably trying to execute it as a node project, which it of course isn't. Try using the [`create-react-app` buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). More about buildpacks [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

Comment: Heroku is not a must, just the first that comes across as what to learn for deployment. @cbr do you know why it would be running it as a node project? I have node installed, but don't believe I instantiated anything related to a server. Also, I will check out the buildpack you mentioned.

Comment: @cbr One of the solutions I found instructed me to run the heroku buildpack as nodejs. As you said, since it's not a node project, I removed the nodejs buildpack from the project.

Comment: Use the [`create-react-app` buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). Heroku probably guesses that since there's a package.json, it's a node project runnable with `npm start`. However, since it's a React project, you need to build the project into static js and html files, and serve those files somehow. That's what the CRA buildpack does. You could also do this yourself by having Heroku run a script that builds the production build and serves them somehow, e.g. with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve).

Comment: Once I emptied my Procfile and followed the CRA buildpack you provided, it's up and running. Thank you! If you want to submit your response, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution :
```

If you have issues using heroku, what you can do, just connect your project to **[NETLIFY][1]**.
 It can be deployed in couple of minutes without any hassle.

```
References :
```

> 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qhkv9w3ezFU&t=7s
> 2. https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/continuous-integration-with-netlify-react-js-d268355c60ed
> 3. https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985
>      [1]: https://www.netlify.com/